# Question about the proof of a limit

Tags: limits, proof-explanation

Here is the picture in question:

[image]

In the proof of $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {\sin x}{x} = 1$$ involving the unit circle, how did they get the height of the largest right triangle to be $\tan(x) $?  Shouldn't it be equivalent to $\sin(x) $?  I feel as if the answer to this question is really obvious, but I've tried solving it by substitution of opposite, adjacent, etc. and it just doesn't work out.

Thanks!

Comment: As the angle goes up to a right angle, notice that the thing in the picture labeled $\sin x$ goes up only as far as $1$, whereas the thing labeled $\tan x$ goes up to $\infty$. That should tell you that it certainly cannot be $\sin x$.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the radius of the circle is 1, then the triangle involving $\tan(x)$ is one whose base is 1 and whose height is some number, say $h$, and whose angle is given by $x$.

In such a case, the "adjacent" side has length 1, and the "opposite" side has length $h$. Thus

$$
\tan(x) = \frac{\text{opposite}}{\text{adjacent}} = \frac{h}{1} = h
$$

so the unknown height is given by $\tan(x)$ as claimed.

Comment: But if you do the same with $sin x$ you get opposite over hypotenuse, hypotenuse is 1, so you get opposite.  That's the same as $tan x$ .

Comment: @Ethan No, hypotenuse is not 1 for the triangle $ABD$ in question.  The hypotenuse is $AD$, which is not $1$.

Comment: @Goos: I'm referring to the hypotenuse AC.  The hypotenuse for the triangle with hypotenuse AC is 1, making both $tan x$ and $sin x$ equal to opposite.

Comment: @Ethan Yes, $\tan x$ and $\sin x$ are both equal to opposite in different cases.  "opposite" means a different thing depending on the triangle.  But if the angle $x$ is the same, then no matter what opposite and adjacent are, $\frac{\text{opposite}}{\text{adjacent}}$ will always be the same value, and we call that $\tan x$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: if you look at the two similars triangles $\hat{ACH}$ and $\hat{ADB}$, you have $$\frac{CH}{AH}=\frac{DB}{AB}$$
$$\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}=\tan(x)=DB$$
denoting $H$ the projection of $C$ on $AB$.

Answer (score 1):

As the angle goes up to a right angle, notice that the thing in the picture labeled $\sin x$ goes up only as far as $1$, whereas the thing labeled $\tan x$ goes up to $\infty$.  That should tell you that it certainly cannot be $\sin x$.

It's the tangent because $\tan$ is opposite over adjacent, and the length of the adjacent side is $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Call the height $H$. Then $\tan x = {\rm opp}/{\rm adj} = H/1 = H$.